# Kivy: editing the line graphic

Tags: python, python-2.7, drawing, kivy

I'm currently using the line graphic to represent edges in a graph. It would be nice to be able to show direction too though!

I'm hoping there's an easy way to change the lines so that they have red tips (or something similar).

I can provide my base code if you want, but currently I have nothing implemented for this at all, I guess it would just give a framework.

One idea I had was to draw an additional line over the current line which is coloured red, however I'm not sure that I can give a single widget multiple lines on the canvas? (This would cause problems).

**Ask if more details are needed :)**

**EDIT:**

Attached code that I'm using to draw and edit lines:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(GraphEdge, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(self.col, 1, 1, 1)
        self.line = Line(points=[100, 200, 200, 200], width = 2.0)
        self.center = ((self.line.points[0]+self.line.points[2])/2,(self.line.points[1]+self.line.points[3])/2)
        self.size = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[0]-self.line.points[2])**2 + (self.line.points[1]-self.line.points[3])**2))]*2
    with self.canvas.after:
        Color(1,0,0,1)
        Line(points=[self.line.points[0],self.line.points[1], 400,400], width = 3)
```

The above code draws the lines, the last part is just showing me drawing a second line on the canvas.

I then need to update the position of these lines, currently my code to do this (for the first line) is as follows:

```
    if self.collide_widget(node):
        distance_from_0 = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[0]-node.center[0])**2 + (self.line.points[1]-node.center[1])**2))]*2
        distance_from_1 = [math.sqrt(((self.line.points[2]-node.center[0])**2 + (self.line.points[3]-node.center[1])**2))]*2

        if distance_from_0 <= distance_from_1:
            if (self.connected_point_0 is False):
                print "collision"                
                if node is not self.connected_node_1:
                    self.connected_point_0 = True
                    self.connected_node_0 = node
                    node.edgeList.append(self)
                    self.line.points = node.center + self.line.points[2:]
                    self.size = 50,50
                    self.center = (self.line.points[2],self.line.points[3])
            return True
```

That is just a snippet to give an idea.

I want to be able to update the second line depending on the position of the first line (there are also some other things to worry about, like the size of the nodes but this can be handled later).

**It is also very likely that this multiple drawing idea is not the best approach, and in fact using something else would make this far easier!**

Comment: I don't see why you can't add multiply lines on the canvas. Just be sure to group them in an InstructionGroup so you can easily add/remove them as a whole.
One idea is to make a class that derives from InstructionGroup and add the lines (base line and the red tip). Then you can just make instances of that class and add it as one canvas instruction.
Btw. check out kivy.garden.graph, it is a great place to start drawing graphs and learning on how to make your own custom graph.

Comment: I hadn't seen either of these things before. I'll try them out and report back,  thanks!

Comment: After looking at garden.graph it isn't really what I'm after. I'm trying to allow creation of network graphs, like in graph theory :)

Comment: I added some sample code to explain what I'm trying to achieve. I can indeed draw multiple lines but I'm not sure how best to update them. This is also going to be quite tricky so I'd like a better approach :D. Is there some way to change the line source graphic?

Comment: So I managed to get the multiple line method to work and it's all going pretty smoothly! Could you post up an answer so I can select it Calvin? I have a new question now, how to rotate the sizebox on the lines! I'll post a new question for this if I can't figure it out though :). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Calvin hasn't responded I'll post the answer myself.

It ended up that drawing multiple lines was the easiest method. Nothing particularly special had to be done.

Comment: No problems! I found the hardest part was managing all the graphics instructions so keep in mind the concept of groups.